# Hibernate - Exporting data into csv file using file writing

Tags: java, hibernate, file, csv

I am trying to export the data from hibernate (using select statement in HQL) to a text file. I using simple file writing mechanism to write the output into the text file. While writing the data into text file, junk values are getting inserted but in SYSO the values are displayed properly.
This may be a small trivial error but I am stuck up in this for a long time.

Any help would be appreciated.

I am also attaching the code

```
public class Logic {
@SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "deprecation" })
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
    cfg.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");

    SessionFactory factory = cfg.buildSessionFactory();
    Session session = factory.openSession();

   File file = new File("D:/Users/output.txt"); 

    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file);
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);


    Query qry = session.createQuery("SELECT A from Employee_details A");
    List l =(List) qry.list();
    System.out.println("Total Number Of Records : "+((java.util.List) l).size());
    Iterator it = ((java.util.List) l).iterator();

    while(it.hasNext())
    {
        Object o = (Object)it.next();
        Employee_details e = (Employee_details)o;
        System.out.println("Employee ID : "+e.getId());
        System.out.println("Employee Name : "+e.getName());
        System.out.println("Employee Salary : "+ e.getSalary());
        System.out.println("----------------------");
        bw.write(e.getId()); // Here instead of Id some junk value is getting inserted
     } 
    bw.flush();
    bw.close();

    }
}
```

Comment: Dont you want to try Apache IOUtils ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Other Hibernate code here
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("D:/Users/output.txt"))); 
System.out.println("Total Number Of Records : "+((java.util.List) l).size());
Iterator it = ((java.util.List) l).iterator();    
while(it.hasNext())
   {
        writer.println(e.getId());
   } 

writer.close(); // put this in finally block
```

Comment: Can you please tell me why File Writer didn't work and printwriter worked. Also how junk values got inserted ?

Comment: Are the "Junk" characters getting appended at the end ?

Comment: No the values which are getting entered itself is junk. Say for example, if e.getId() has the value as 101, the data which is getting inserted into the file is 'g'.